# MySQL escape string

Tags: go

How can I filter input from URL param example
localhost:8080/v1/data/:id

And I want to use filter like `mysql_real_escape_string` param for id in Golang, I can't use `?` cause this filter is dynamic, this param can be use or no, like this example

```
if status != "99" {
    where = append(where, "vs.stats = '1'")
}

if cari != "" {
    where = append(where, "(lm.title_member like '%"+cari+"%' OR " +
    "lm.nama_member like '%"+cari+"%' )")
}

query := "select vs.*, lm.nama_member from volks_shift vs left join list_member lm on vs.id_m=lm.id_m where vs.id_s=?"

rows, err := s.DB.QueryContext(ctx, query, id_s)
```

and I want secure cari val, without use `?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no escape function in the `database/sql` package, see related issue [#18478](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/18478) (and it's also not nice to invoke a mysql-specific function when using a database abstraction layer).

But it is also not needed as you can still use `?` in a dynamic query. Just build the query parameters dynamically together with the query, like so:

```
    query := "SELECT vs.*, lm.nama_member" +
        " FROM volks_shift vs LEFT JOIN list_member lm ON vs.id_m=lm.id_m" +
        " WHERE vs.id_s=?"
    params := []interface{}{id_s}

    if status != "99" {
        query += " AND vs.stats = '1'"
    }

    if cari != "" {
        query += " AND (lm.title_member LIKE ? OR lm.nama_member LIKE ?)"
        params = append(params, "%"+cari+"%", "%"+cari+"%")
    }

    rows, err := s.DB.QueryContext(ctx, query, params...)
```